# How to make page scrolling horizantally first then scrolling vertically

Tags: javascript, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqYCJ.gif)

I would like to create a page with a similar effect like the gif pic posted.

There are two sections of the page, first one is horizontal section, second one is verical section.

when you scrolling the mouse wheel, the page scroll horizontally first. then it scrolls vertically after it reaches the bottom of the horizontal section.

Somehow, I have on idea how should I set the height of the horizontal section and what is the ratio of trasnlate I should apply on the horizontal section, so that the last element in the horizontal section could take entire space of current view when you scroll to a specific height. Then, you can start scroll vertically to the next section.

I tried to replicate it. Here is link of what I have done so far.

Thank you in advance.

https://codepen.io/hongxuli/pen/eYRywRM

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('.slider-inner')
let sliderWidth = slider.getBoundingClientRect().width

document.querySelector(".horizontal").style.height = `${
      sliderWidth * window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth
    }px`

function animate() {
    let y = window.scrollY
    let precent = y/sliderWidth // what this precent should be ? 
    slider.style.transform = `translateX(-${precent*100}%)`
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

animate()
```

```css
.horizontal{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw; 
    //height -- what is the relationship of this height and total width of items

}

.slider-container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-inner{
    display: flex;
    width: 200vw;
}


.item{
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh ;
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 1px black;
}


.vertical{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="vertical"></div>
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing it is not clear

Comment: I hope the page could be scrolled vertically when the last item in the horizontal section takes the entire space of the current view. And at the same time, the horizontal section should not keep moving toward the left side.

Comment: my problem is the last item in the horizontal section is still moving toward the left while the vertical section start enters the current veiw.